# Position: fixed in React native Webview behaves inconsistently on iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I am trying to display code generated SVGs using a Webview. The following component behaves as I need to on Android, but the svg won't fit the webview on iOS/

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import WebView from "react-native-webview";


function TestComp() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <View style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}>
                <WebView source={{ html }}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default TestComp;


const html = `<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body { background-color: blue; }
    svg {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 75 135">
        <circle cx="38.2" cy="25.7" r="25.7"/>
        <path d="M56.5,134h-38c-10.1,0-18.3-8.2-18.3-18.3v-38c0-10.1,8.2-18.3,18.3-18.3h38 c10.1,0,18.3,8.2,18.3,18.3v38C74.8,125.8,66.6,134,56.5,134z"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>`;
```

**Android (proper result)**:

[image]

**iOS, clipped**:

[image]

**I am thinking that iOS is not handling `position: fixed` like android... but I have no idea why and how to fix it. Any solution?**

Answer (score 0):

I partially fixed it by adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` to my html.